# Is it possible to extract data from Excel Bar Graph with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have thousand of data in Excel to be extracted, but unfortunately they are in bar graph.
[image]

I have tried to extract by using VBA Macro script

```
Sub GetChartValues()
   Dim NumberOfRows As Integer
   Dim X As Object
   Counter = 2

   ' Calculate the number of rows of data.
   NumberOfRows = UBound(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values)

   Worksheets("ChartData").Cells(1, 1) = "X Values"

   ' Write x-axis values to worksheet.
   With Worksheets("ChartData")
      .Range(.Cells(2, 1), _
      .Cells(NumberOfRows + 1, 1)) = _
      Application.Transpose(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues)
   End With

   ' Loop through all series in the chart and write their values to
   ' the worksheet.
   For Each X In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
      Worksheets("ChartData").Cells(1, Counter) = X.Name

      With Worksheets("ChartData")
         .Range(.Cells(2, Counter), _
         .Cells(NumberOfRows + 1, Counter)) = _
         Application.Transpose(X.Values)
      End With

      Counter = Counter + 1
   Next

End Sub
```

And it works, but it only gives result as in the image

[image]

Those are not the one I wanted, what I want for example, boys in school A in city B contributes 45%, boys in school C in city D contributes 43%, so the boys average is 44%. The question, Is it possible to extract unseen excel data which compose the final average percentages? What I want is the data, columns behind the scene, like name of schools, which cities, etc.

Comment: You extracted the data exactly, 0.4416 equals 44.16%. All you need to do is adjust the cell format to a percentage.

Comment: I am sorry, perhaps i need to edit my question